# Annotations not converted properly after changing code from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-annotations

After converting some Java code to Kotlin (to create a ReplacementSpan), an annotation-related error is returned.

`from` in the `@IntRange(from = 0)` constructor returns an error:

> 'IntRange' is not an annotation class | Cannot find a parameter with this name: from

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawRect
import android.text.style.ReplacementSpan

class HrSpan : ReplacementSpan() {
    override fun getSize(
        paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, @IntRange(from = 0) start: Int,
        @IntRange(from = 0) end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?
    ): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun draw(
        canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, @IntRange(from = 0) start: Int,
        @IntRange(from = 0) end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int,
        paint: Paint
    ) {
        canvas.drawRect(x, top.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), (top + 8).toFloat(), paint)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin confuses its own [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/index.html) class with the [`IntRange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntRange) annotation of the Android SDK.

Make an import like that giving it another name:

For Android Support library:

```
import android.support.annotation.IntRange as AndroidIntRange
```

For AndroidX:

```
import androidx.annotation.IntRange as AndroidIntRange
```

and use it like this:

```
fun foo(@AndroidIntRange(from = 0, to = 255) bar: Int) {
}
```

Comment: for AndroidX you must import androidx.annotation.IntRange  as AndroidIntRange                                               https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/IntRange